# Javascript prompt missed when reloading the site

Tags: javascript, firefox

At the start of my page, there comes a prompt. This prompt is important for the following process (loading data from database). If i press F5 to reload the site, the prompt should pop-up again. In Chrome and Edge that is working fine. Just firefox doesn't show anything after a reload of the page. After pressing F5 again, the prompt is coming up regularly.

Here's my code:

function:

```
<script>
function feststellung(maxStationenanzahl) {
    var station = window.prompt("Bitte Stationsnummer eingeben", "");
    if (station != null && station != "" && station <= maxStationenanzahl && isNaN(station) == false) {
        location.href = "station.php?stationsnr=" + station;
    }
    else {
        alert("Die Eingabe ist Keine Zahl, entspricht nicht der Stationsnummer oder ist leer");
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

call:

```
if(isset($_GET['stationsnr']) && $_GET['stationsnr'] != "" ){
    echo("<body>");
}
else{
    echo("<body onload='feststellung(".$letzte_aufgabe.")'>"); 
}
```

How to fix this in Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. do not use body onload inline.
2. have
   `if("" == trim($_GET['stationsnr'])){ 
     echo "<script>feststellung('".$letzte_aufgabe."')</script>"; 
   }`
   just before the `</body>` tag to always execute
3. better: Ajax the data in without reloading the page

The test could be written like this:

```
var reg = /^\d+$/; 
function feststellung(maxStationenanzahl) {
  var station = window.prompt("Bitte Stationsnummer eingeben", "");
  if (station.trim() !="" && reg.test(station) && parseInt(station,10) <= maxStationenanzahl) {
    location..replace("station.php?stationsnr=" + station);
  }
  else {
    alert("Die Eingabe ist Keine Zahl, entspricht nicht der Stationsnummer oder ist leer");
    location.reload();
  } 
}
```